# Haskell function :: [Name] -> [[(Name, Bool)]]

Tags: haskell

Given the following:

```
type Name = String
envs :: [Name] -> [[(Name , Bool)]]
```

I have to implement 'envs' so that given a list of Names, it returns all possible combinations of Names and booleans

My attempt didn't return all possible combinations, this was my code:

```
envs xxs@(x:xs) = [[ (name, value) | name <- xxs  , value <- [False, True] ]]
```

the expected results for

```
envs ["P", "Q"]
```

are:

```
[ [ ("P",False)
  , ("Q",False)
  ]
, [ ("P",False)
  , ("Q",True)
  ]
, [ ("P",True)
  , ("Q",False)
  ]
, [ ("P",True)
  , ("Q",True)
  ]
]
```

But, mine were:

```
[[("P",True),("Q",True)],[("P",False),("Q",False)]]
```

So what is the proper implementation of the 'envs' function, the one that returns the expected result?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard  what is the proper implementation of the 'envs' function?

Comment: `envs = mapM (flip fmap (,) (flip fmap [False, True]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is get all combinations of `True` and `False` for the number of names, which can be done easily with `replicateM` specialised to lists:

```
replicateM (length names) [False, True]
```

E.g. if `length names == 2`, then this produces:

```
[ [False, False]
, [False, True]
, [True, False]
, [True, True]
]
```

What remains is just to zip each of these with the names themselves:

```
envs names =
  [ zip names values
  | let n = length names
  , values <- replicateM n [False, True]
  ]
```

For `envs ["P", "Q"]` this produces:

```
[ [("P", False), ("Q", False)]
, [("P", False), ("Q", True)]
, [("P", True), ("Q", False)]
, [("P", True), ("Q", True)]
]
```

And it works for any number of inputs, even 0, for which your original implementation would fail since you don’t match `[]`. It always returns 2<sup>n</sup> assignments:

```
-- 2^0 == 1
envs [] == [[]]

-- 2^3 == 8
envs ["P", "Q", "R"] ==
  [ [("P", False), ("Q", False), ("R", False)]
  , [("P", False), ("Q", False), ("R", True)]
  , [("P", False), ("Q", True), ("R", False)]
  , [("P", False), ("Q", True), ("R", True)]
  , [("P", True), ("Q", False), ("R", False)]
  , [("P", True), ("Q", False), ("R", True)]
  , [("P", True), ("Q", True), ("R", False)]
  , [("P", True), ("Q", True), ("R", True)]
  ]
```

Comment: If you're going to give away the solution to this exercise, you should give the good one hinted at in the comments on the question itself: `envs = mapM (\name -> [(name, False), (name, True)])`.